# Trying to parse JSON string, unexpected number

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse this JSON:

```
var json = '{"material":"Gummislang 3\/4\" 30 m (utanp\u00e5liggande sk\u00e5p)"}'
```

I run `JSON.parse(json)` but i get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` when doing so. I have tried this in Google Chrome. I don't know what the problem is since I can take the JSON string and put it in any JSON validator and it claims that the JSON is valid. Shouldn't the browser be able to parse it?

Comment: Don't use string literals containing JSON! Use object literals instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are inserting a JSON object representation into a JavaScript string without properly escaping the representation.

To avoid having to do this, remove the quotes you are adding around the representation, and skip the `JSON.parse(json)` – the default output from PHP's `json_encode()` is valid JavaScript when used in this context.

For security, you should specify the `JSON_HEX_TAG` option if possible. This will prevent cross-site scripting in cases where the JSON might end up inside a document parsed as XML. (And for XML documents, the JSON should be inside a CDATA section as well.)

Comment: To sum up, replace `\"` with `\\"` to insert a literal backslash.

Comment: Genius! I didn't realise i could use it right away without doing all the parsing! :)

Answer (score 4):

You're validating the *string literal*, which is a valid JSON string containing invalid JSON.  You need to validate the value of the string, which is not valid JSON.

If you paste the string value into a JSON validator, you'll see that the error comes from this part:

```
"material": "Gummislang 3/4"30m
```

The `"` needs to be escaped.

Comment: To clarify for the OP, he needs to use `\\"` to escape it; the first backslash escapes the second, so that it will escape inside the actual JSON.